# How can I see the Browser Version on a google analytic report?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

Looking at other questions with answers on here, there seems to be a "browser version" filter for GAnalytics reports, but I'm unable to find them. I've seen it listed here: [Google Analytics: how to consolidate browser counts by major version number?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114968/google-analytics-how-to-consolidate-browser-counts-by-major-version-number)
and here: [Can I use Google Analytics to show visits by browser as a percentage of total visits?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51724/can-i-use-google-analytics-to-show-visits-by-browser-as-a-percentage-of-total-vi), but I can't find it in my Analytics dashboard.

Obviously, these are old questions, so I'm wondering if this was an old feature.

If it is, is there any way to customize a report that would include browser versions?

[image: Would like to see browser version here on my Google Analytics page]

Answer (score 3):

In Google Analytics 4, go to **Explore** -> **Free-form**, and set the following **dimensions**:

1. Browser
2. Browser version

In **Rows**, add:

1. Browser
2. Browser version

You should see the browser and browser version on the right:

[image: Browser Version in GA4]